Powershell ISE won't autoload scripts
If I write a Powershell script, save it as

C:\Users\username\OneDrive - CompanyName\Documents\Code\Demo.ps1

and double-click the file in Windows Explorer to launch it, Powershell ISE starts with the error message

Unable to load C:\Users\username\OneDrive - CompanyName: Could not
find file 'C;\Users\username\OneDrive - CompanyName'.

It doesn't matter what the script is; the same script will run if I load it manually into ISE. It appears to be caused by the space in the folder name for OneDrive, because it will load without error if I copy the script to D:\ and double-click it there.
Why is it that ultra-modern Powershell cannot handle the ultra-modern feature of a space in the path? Or, less sarcastically, is there a solution?

Two things: 1) PowerShell ISE is the opposite of "ultra-modern PowerShell", it was abandoned >5 years ago, and 2) it sounds more like ISE is having trouble with OneDrive's projected file system - does the problem go away if you wait a second and double-click the same file again? Does it ever occur with paths that have spaces but aren't part of your OneDrive clients target paths?

Interesting, Mathias. It would be nice if MS at a bare minimum let users know this when PS ISE launches... but then, it's MS.
No, the problem doesn't go away if you wait a second.  And you were right; placing the script inside "D:\A Folder With Spaces" allows double-clicking to work.

As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is no longer actively developed and there are reasons not to use it (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is Visual Studio Code with its PowerShell extension.

That's nice to know, but really useless in this case. My work computer is massively locked down by IT. VS Code is not really an option.

That's unfortunate to hear, but remember that any responses here - whether comments or answers - aren't only directed to the asker, but also to future readers. Note that there's also a way to install VS Code in a user-specific manner, which doesn't require elevation (administrative privileges).
